# MediaElement on Fullscreen doesn't fire touch events (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: c#, xaml, events, mediaelement

I am developing Windows Phone app and I am using `MediaElement` as my video player control. 
There is one control on the page which contains the `MediaElement` and when I tap on it I am starting to play the video, on another tap I want the `MediaElement` to be FullScreen - so I am using:

```
_mediaElement.IsFullWindow = true
```

However, when I want to get back from the fullscreen mode I cannot catch onTap events of `MediaElement`.

How can I catch touch events of MediaElement when it is fullscreen? Or is there any other way to overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got the solution for this. I am also looking for the same

Comment: No, I am using the hardware button for getting back (from fullscreen). I don't think that it's possible since MeidaElement FullScreeen runs in different process :(

Comment: Oh.. Thanks for your comment. I Hope if someone finds the solution or any other methodology to achieve this and update here.